# nodejs WebSocket.send() is not sending if method is parametrized

Tags: javascript, websocket

I`ve just stuck to an interesting moment.
In my server I am implementing the WebSocket. Inside of ws.on('connection') method, I am having two variants of the same function:

1-st is working perfectly

2nd, which differs only by the parameter - is also working, but is not sending the message to client. 
the code:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});

wss.on('connection', function(ws){
   var timerR;

   // 1
   function startTheInterval1(){
      timerR = setInterval( function() {
         if (a >= 0){
            ws.send('message ' + a);  // Client recieves the message
            clearInterval(timerR);
         } 
      }, 1000);
   }
   startTheInterval1();

   // 2
   function startTheInterval2(flag){
      timerR = setInterval( function() {
         if (flag >= 0){
            ws.send('message ' + flag);   // Client don`t see the message
            clearInterval(timerR);
         } 
      }, 1000);
   }
   startTheInterval2(a);

   // some other code with socket
}
```

Seems I am missing something about JavaScript. So the question is: Why do the second variant is not working properly?

Comment: Doing polling every 1000ms is not an ideal approach. Can you explain what `a` represents in this sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first function refers to a global `a` that can change value between intervals.

Your second function refers to a local `a` that will never change value.

All primitive types in JavaScript are passed by value. Only objects and arrays are passed by reference. That's why your second function does not work.